# How does Velen's Future sight interact with heal absorption?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

The legendary healer trinket [**Velen's Future Sight**](http://www.wowhead.com/item=144258/velens-future-sight) redistributes 50% of overheal to 3 other nearby targets through "smart healing".

How exactly does this redistribution work in combination with healing absorption effects?

The two first things that come to my mind here are the healing shields from the Sisters of the Moon encounter and the [**Overflowing**](http://www.wowhead.com/affix=1/overflowing) mythic+ affix.

Sisters:

- Are players with a healing absorption shield considered to be valid targets for the smart-healing?

Overflowing:

- Is 50% of overheal "removed" from the debuff shield?
- Can the redistribution remove healing absorption from from the shield that is caused by the same heling spell that caused the overheal?

Comment: Note: Overflowing was removed, I think, because some classes ended up getting healing absorb shields of millions of HP, while others didn't even notice it.

Comment: This probably won't suit as answer because it's based off some thinking with no source, so I'll give it a try in here: It's pretty much a No.. while Velen's smart heals only affect players with less than full hp (it even says "injured") the Sisters' shield does exactly what a priest shield would do, just inverted (soaking up healing instead of damage). So if your entire raid is stacked at full hp, Velen would not distribute the healing correctly. With the 15% healing buff it's still a very strong option for getting rid of the shields, though.